# nativescript switch if checked = true drop an error why?

Tags: angular, mobile, nativescript, uiswitch

my code in html:

```
<Switch col="2" row="0" class="switcher" color="#FFFFFF" backgroundColor="#DCA44F" offBackgroundColor="#B8B8B8" 
                        checked="{{isNightlyMode}}" (checkedChange)="onCheckedChange()"></Switch>
```

when the begin value of isNightlyMode = false -> everything is ok.
if the begin value of isNightlyMode=true, drop an error and doesnt load my page:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTrackDrawable' of undefined
```

JS: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTrackDrawable' of undefined
JS:     at Switch.setNativeBackgroundColor (file: src/webpack:/libri-app/node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/switch/index.android.js:48:0)
JS:     at Switch._onCheckedPropertyChanged (file: src/webpack:/libri-app/node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/switch/index.android.js:61:0)
JS:     at onCheckedPropertyChanged (file: src/webpack:/libri-app/node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/switch/switch-common.js:22:0)
JS:     at Switch.Property.set [as checked] (file: src/webpack:/libri-app/node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/properties/index.js:178:0)
JS:     at CheckedValueAccessor.writeValue (file: src/webpack:/libri-app/node_modules/@nativescript/angular/fesm2015/nativescript-angular.mjs:4993:8)
JS:     at onChange (file: src/webpack:/libri-app/node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm2015/forms.mjs:3172:26)
JS:     at file: src/webpack:/libri-app/node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm2015/forms.mjs:3658:49
JS:     at Array.forEach ()
JS:     at FormControl.setValue (file: src/webpack:/libri-app/node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm2015/forms.mjs:3658:27)
JS:     at file: src/webpack:/libri-app/node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm2015/forms.mjs:4147:25

my code in .ts file:

```
onCheckedChange() {
this.isNightlyMode = ! this.isNightlyMode;
console.log('nightly '+this.isNightlyMode);
```

}

What can I do?